# Problems with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
const { userChoice } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentGuess === 60) {
      console.log(userChoice);
    }
  });
```

The above code works fine

```
const { userChoice } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userChoice === 60) {
      console.log(userChoice);
    }
  });
```

The above does not work. Also, the one below does not work

```
const { userChoice } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentGuess === userChoice) {
      console.log(userChoice);
    }
  });
```

Everytime I include `userChoice` in the condition, code will not work. What I want to achieve is for console.log to run when `currentGuess` equals `userChoice`. But everytime I include `userChoice` in the condition, code does not work. Please help

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Alert } from "react-native";
import Card from "../component/Card";
import NumberContainer from "../component/NumberContainer";

function suggestedNumber(min, max, excNumber) {
  const rndNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  if (rndNumber === excNumber) {
    return suggestedNumber(min, max, excNumber);
  } else {
    return rndNumber;
  }
}
function randomNumber(min, max) {
  const randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  return randNumber;
}

function GameScreen(props) {
  const lowerNumber = useRef(1);
  const higherNumber = useRef(100);
  const [currentGuess, setCurrentGuess] = useState(
    suggestedNumber(lowerNumber.current, higherNumber.current, props.userChoice)
  );
  const { userChoice } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentGuess === userChoice) {
      console.log(userChoice);
    }
  }, [currentGuess, userChoice]);
  function suggestLower(e) {
    if (currentGuess < props.userChoice && e === "lower") {
      Alert.alert("Wrong", "Number needs to be higher", [
        {
          text: "Close",
          style: "cancel",
        },
      ]);
    } else {
      higherNumber.current = currentGuess;
      setCurrentGuess(randomNumber(lowerNumber.current, higherNumber.current));
    }
  }

  function suggestHigher(e) {
    if (currentGuess > props.userChoice && e === "greater") {
      Alert.alert("Wrong", "Number needs to be lower", [
        {
          text: "Close",
          style: "cancel",
        },
      ]);
    } else {
      lowerNumber.current = currentGuess;
      setCurrentGuess(randomNumber(lowerNumber.current, higherNumber.current));
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainDisplay}>
      <Text>Opponent's Guess</Text>
      <NumberContainer>{currentGuess}</NumberContainer>
      <Card style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button title="Lower" onPress={suggestLower.bind(this, "lower")} />
        <Button title="Greater" onPress={suggestHigher.bind(this, "greater")} />
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainDisplay: {
    alignItems: "center",
    alignContent: "space-between",
    height: 200,

    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    flexDirection: "row",
    width: "70%",
    paddingVertical: 20,
  },
});

export default GameScreen;
```

Comment: For us to help, we'll need to know the code which sets `userChoice`'s value. Apparently, it's not set to 60.

Comment: I have posted the complete code

Comment: Is `userChoice` a number? Or could it be a string?

Comment: userChoice is a number

Comment: 1. you can remove `currentGuess` from the dependency array as that's the state of the component, and if that changes, the component rerenders!

2. try parsing the `userChoice` and `currentGuess` to integers by using `parseInt()` or just adding a `+` sign in front of the variables (make sure to add a null check too!).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you, I found my mistake. The value of userChoice is from a `<TextInput>` field. I added a `parseInt(userChoice)` and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** The above problem statement is not enough to identify the issue,
can you elaborate more?

---

I think you should add a dependency array as the second argument to `useEffect` hook like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (currentGuess === userChoice) {
        console.log(userChoice);
    }
}, [currentGuess, userChoice]);
```

This ensures that your callback method will be executed whenever your variables in the dependency array (i.e., `[currentGuess, userChoice]`) changes.

Comment: They left the dependency array out, so it's already running on every render

Comment: @NicholasTower true that, question is not clear to identify the issue!

Comment: It still does not work after adding the dependency array. I have posted the complete code

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of UserChoice? That is causing it to "not work". You are using === so it will also need to be the same data type.

Comment: Thank you, I found my mistake. The value of userChoice is from a `<TextInput>` field. I added a parseInt(userChoice) and it worked. Thank you